# Rename csv file in a folder based on first row value

Tags: powershell

I am very new to Powershell and would like some help please.
I have csv files in a folder and would like to rename each file based on the first row value.

For example

csvFile#1
StudentID,EnglishM,MathsM
900212,90,80

csvFile#2
StudentID,EnglishM,MathsM
900213,92,88

csvFile#2
StudentID,EnglishM,MathsM
900214,97,81

Output
csvFile#1: 900212_currentdateTime
csvFile#2: 900213_currentdateTime
csvFile#3: 900214_currentdateTime

Comment: $folderPath = "C:\Users\In\"
$folderPathDest = "C:\Users\In\Sort\"

$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Input\demo.csv"
$filename = "$($csv[1].StudentID)_$(get-date -f yyyymmdd_HHmmss).csv"
$csv | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Set-Location "CSV Files path"
Get-ChildItem *.csv |
  Foreach {
    $csv = import-csv $_.fullname
    $n = $csv.StudentID+"_"+(get-date).tostring("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss")+".csv"
    Rename-Item $_.fullname -newname $n
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I modified "CSV Files path" to the folder directory and ended in "…...\".

Comment: Where is the filed saved to?

Comment: ok I believe I got one file renamed by applying the following code
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Input\demo.csv" $filename = "$($csv[1].StudentID)_$(get-date -f yyyymmdd_HHmmss).csv" $csv | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
I would like to apply and rename to all files in the folder as in below and output the renamed file in the 'sort' folder
$folderPath = "C:\Users\In" $folderPathDest = "C:\Users\In\Sort"
Could someone please help me to create a loop to rename all files in the folder?

Comment: This worked for me for 3 csv file in a folder where the folder had 3, means all

Comment: Just could not get your code to work - as for set-location "Do I enter my file path here?" - to which I did but did not seem to work